# Remove the last comma in SQL UPDATE statement using StrUtils in Delphi

Tags: sql, string, delphi, sql-update

Assume that we have this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE article SET saison='12E', mode='ECH', client='SAS', WHERE ID='3448fe81-1bec-e011-8546-001f3ccf8f20'
```

This SQL statement is generated by concatenated strings like this:

```
// saison change
procedure TarticleEditForm.saisonComboChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
    SQLQuery := SQLQuery + 'saison=''' + saisonCombo.Text + ''',';
end;

// client change
procedure TarticleEditForm.clientComboChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
    SQLQuery := SQLQuery + 'client=''' + clientCombo.Text + ''',';
end;
.
.
.
```

As you see, there is a comma before "WHERE" clause. How can I remove the last comma to have the correct statement:

```
UPDATE article SET saison='12E', mode='ECH', client='SAS' WHERE ID='3448fe81-1bec-e011-8546-001f3ccf8f20'
```

RMQ: the number of comma is not fixe, it can be 1, 2, 5...

### thank you.

The solution is replacing ", WHERE" by "WHERE"

```
 SQLQuery := StringReplace(SQLQuery , ', WHERE', 'WHERE', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

I am using this to trace every change in HISTORY Table.
Thank you all.

Comment: I'm guessing this is an sql statement that's dynamically generated... instead of trying to remove the comma, how about figuring out how to fix the code that generates the comma in the place, so it doesn't show up at all?

Comment: What if any combo is changed more than once?

Comment: You do realize that you've got serious SQL injection vulnerabilities in the code you've posted, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than concatenating the changes to the SQL string as they happen, store them in a collection and build you SQL string after all the options have been evaluated.

Then you will know how many fields are going to be changed and build the statement correctly. Of course this will require you to store not only the value but also the name of the fild being changed:

[pseudo code]

```
for i=0 to fields_changed.count {
  sql = sql + fields_changed(i).field_name + " = " + fields_changed(i).new_value
  if i < fields_changed.count {
    sql = sql + ", "
  }
}
sql = sql + " WHERE ..."
```

**EDIT:** The other option you have is to simply perform a string replace on `, WHERE` with `WHERE` just before executing the statement; since the word 'where' is a reserved word and should not occur more than once in your SQL statement. This may be the simpler solution even if it feels like a bit of a hack.

Comment: I usually end up this kind of stuff when generating code (hate doing string manipulation to clean up the generated string; it seems hacky in the bad sense.) I've been accused of over-engineering for it more than once, so one needs to be aware of it too.

Answer (score 2):

another option is to reduce the length of the string by 1 character before appending the WHERE clause.